# How to Convert Nested Object in Key Value Pair in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object

**I want to do this with programming**

**Problem**

```
  attributes: {
    allow: [ '0' ],
    create: [ '0' ],
    all: [ '0' ],
    rfid: [ '0' ],
}
```

**What I want is**

```
  attributes: {
    allow:'0',
    create: '0',
    all:'0',
    rfid: '0',
}
```

Comment: for (var key in attributes) attributes[key] = attributes[key][0]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Functional approach:**

You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to turn an object `{ a: 1, b: 2 }` into an array of arrays (containing pairs of keys and values) `[['a', 1], ['b', 2]]`. You can then use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to apply an operation on each and mapping each element of the array to the return value of the operation. In our case, we'll actually have something like `[['allow', ['0']], ...]` at that point and want to map it to `[['allow', '0'], ...]`. Then at the end, we undo the first operation using [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to get an object back.

The mapping operation can be simply `([k, [v]]) => [k, v]`. Using destructuring, we get an expressive way of extracting the value that we need and returning it.

Now since the whole thing seems to be inside another object with `attributes` as key (and I don't know if there can be other keys), we'll return another such object with `attributes` replaced and the other keys preserved:

```js
function transform (object) {
  return {
    ...object,
    attributes: Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(object.attributes).map(([k, [v]]) => [k, v])
    )
  }
}
```

---

**Imperative approach:**

This approach is simpler, but will mutate your object. You can loop over the keys in the `attributes` object and replace each value with its own first array element, as follows:

```js
function transform (object) {
  for (const key in object.attributes) {
    object.attributes[key] = object.attributes[key][0]
  }
  
  return object
}
```